# How to add items to group in GroupedList (Office UI Fabric React)

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

How to map items to a specific group? On the IGroup interface it's possible to add subgroups but the items are added to the component directly. Is there a property that needs to be set on the item to match to a specific group?

The documentation and sample on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/groupedlist doesn't really help much here.

Comment: Try using the "Export to Codepen" option right above the code example in the docs. Then log out `this._items` and `this._groups` inside the `render` method (you'll have to check the output in your browser console, since Codepen won't show it in their console). This should give you a good idea of how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, startIndex was what I was searching for. Unfortunately it's not possible to assign items on different levels as they are all displayed with the same indent. Too bad.